# Key Framing Multiple Objects At Once

Tags: keyframes, rigidbody

I have a cube that I have fractured (using cell fracture) and I'd like to know how I can keyframe the animation tick box under the rigid body section. When I select all of them and keyframe the animation tick box, only the fracture that has been primarily selected gets the keyframes and I want them all to be keyframed at once

Also, I am using 2.79 because I need to for an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>  to link the data from the Active Object to the selected Objects (the fractured pieces).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this commercial add-on, **[Key Selected Objects](https://blastframe.com/product/key-selected-objects/)**, which lets you add/delete keys for multiple objects from the user interface:
[image: Key Selected Objects]